# Why won't my Laravel collection filter correctly by date?

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

I have

```
  $dt = Carbon::now();
  $b4 = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(12);

  Event::orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->where('date', '<', $b4)
    ->where('ends', '>=', $dt)
    ->orWhere('date', '>=', $dt)
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

All filters work except the first `where`. I tried it following the `orWhere` first, no dice. It displays items with the date in August 2018. Help?

Comment: Could you write the SQL query you'd like to have ? I see nothing wrong with the results you get with this code.

Comment: Well 12 weeks from now would be February, so August is out of my specified range.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to group your where queries ie.

```
  $dt = Carbon::now();
  $b4 = Carbon::now()->addWeeks(12);

  Event::orderBy('date', 'desc')
    ->where(function ($query) use ($dt, $b4) {
        $query->where('date', '<', $b4->format('Y-m-d'))
        ->where('ends', '>=', $dt->format('Y-m-d'));
    })
    ->orWhere('date', '>=', $dt->format('Y-m-d'))
    ->take(3)
    ->get();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queries#parameter-grouping

Comment: Lee, what do I prepend to the second where method (first in the function)? I can't just run (nothing)->where

Comment: Sorry I had a typo. Please have another look. But not sure what you mean?..  There is no nothing query. Its a closure  to group the first 2 wheres. If nothing then it falls back to the orWhere query.

Comment: yeah that produces the same exact results, no dice, so strange

Comment: Are the date columns datetime or date?  If date you should be using $dt->format('Y-m-d').. Its hard to help more without seeing the data.. But using what I have above will work with the correct data.

Comment: Damn; the Event date columns are just dates indeed, but the formatting still makes no difference. I really appreciate your help, by the way.